# Access bintary repos is forbidden

Tags: android, dependencies

I am trying to build a Github android project. It has some dependencies that are located in bintary, but accessing those repositories is forbidden. This is one of those errors:

Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/asf/asf/com/asfoundation/appcoins-contract-proxy/0.4.5.19b/appcoins-contract-proxy-0.4.5.19b.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

How can I resolve those dependencies?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [That library](https://github.com/AppStoreFoundation/asf-sdk) seems to be largely abandoned. Most likely, you will either need to switch to something else or compile that library yourself.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, Actually, I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/Aptoide/aptoide-client-v8). It is an updated project that uses that library. How can they do that?

Comment: You would have to ask them, as it looks like you have via an issue. The `app/build.gradle` file has not been updated since April, which would have been before the Bintray shutdown if I remember the dates for all of that correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have already opened an issue on the project's Github, but they have not answered yet. Also, I sent an email to one of the developers. Based on [this link](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), it seems they shut down the Bintary.